# Send Emails with or without Inline images depending on value in cell

Tags: google-apps-script

Good afternoon. I'm using the code below to send emails with inline images retrieved by ID from a cell in spreadsheet. However, if the cell with the inline image ID is blank, the script does not send the message.
Is there a way to tweak this code to make it work in both cases? (with and without an ID value in cell)
Thanks

````
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('SendMail')
  var lr = ss.getLastRow();

  var quotaLeft = MailApp.getRemainingDailyQuota();
  //Logger.log(quotaLeft);

  if((lr-1) > quotaLeft) {
     Browser.msgBox("You have " + quotaLeft + " left and you're trying to send " + (lr-1) + " emails. Emails were not send.");
  } else {



    for (var i = 2;i<=lr;i++){


      var currentEmail = ss.getRange(i, 1).getValue();
      var currentSubject = ss.getRange(i, 2).getValue();
      var templateText = ss.getRange(i, 3).getValue();
      var currentname = ss.getRange(i, 4).getValue();
      var reply = ss.getRange(i, 5).getValue();


      Logger.log("Cell: " + ss.getRange(i, 6).getA1Notation());
      Logger.log("Image: "+ DriveApp.getFileById(ss.getRange(i, 6).getValue()));

      var image = DriveApp.getFileById(ss.getRange(i, 6).getValue()).getBlob();

      var message = templateText.replace("{name}",currentname);
      message += "<br/><br/><img src=\"cid:sampleImage\">";

      MailApp.sendEmail({

        to: currentEmail,
        replyTo: reply,
        subject: currentSubject,
        htmlBody: message,
        inlineImages: {sampleImage: image},    
      });


    } //close for loop

  } //close else statement

} //close sendEmails```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it.

The changes will also catch and an error that may occur if the image ID is incorrect or the file format is incorrect.

````
  function sendMail(){

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('SendMail')
  var lr = ss.getLastRow();

  var quotaLeft = MailApp.getRemainingDailyQuota();
  //Logger.log(quotaLeft);

   if((lr-1) > quotaLeft) {
     Browser.msgBox("You have " + quotaLeft + " left and you're trying to send " + 
    (lr-1) + " emails. Emails were not send.");
   } else {

    for (var i = 2;i<=lr;i++){

  var currentEmail = ss.getRange(i, 1).getValue();
  var currentSubject = ss.getRange(i, 2).getValue();
  var templateText = ss.getRange(i, 3).getValue();
  var currentname = ss.getRange(i, 4).getValue();
  var reply = ss.getRange(i, 5).getValue();
  var imageFile = ss.getRange(i, 6).getValue();
  var image = ""
   Logger.log("Cell: " + ss.getRange(i, 6).getA1Notation());
   Logger.log("Image: "+ DriveApp.getFileById(ss.getRange(i, 6).getValue()));

    if(imageFile){
     try{
    image = DriveApp.getFileById(imageFile).getBlob();
      } catch (e) {
   templateText += "<p>Image merge failed: " + e;         
   }
  }

  var message = templateText.replace("{name}",currentname);
  message += "<br/><br/><img src=\"cid:sampleImage\">";

  if(image){
  MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: currentEmail,
    replyTo: reply,
    subject: currentSubject,
    htmlBody: message,
    inlineImages: {sampleImage: image},    
  });

    } else {

  MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: currentEmail,
    replyTo: reply,
    subject: currentSubject,
    htmlBody: message,  
  });
}

    } //close for loop

  } //close else statement

 } //close sendEmails```
````

Comment: Awesome solution. Many thanks. I will post an extension request of this script (working with several inline images, not just one) on a new thread. Thanks so much

Comment: Hi again. I was testing this script. First with 2 spreadsheets with one row only, one with and image Id and another without any image Id, and it worked properly for both. However, for a spreadsheet with 2 rows, the first row with an image ID and the second row without it actually sends both emails WITH the inline image. Also in the second email the text message loses its html formatting. Do you know why is this happening? Thanks

Comment: @VíctorEnrich Chang the var image = "" and inside the if statement as above.

As for the HTML it works as expected for me without looking at your HTML I can't say

Comment: Thanks. This variation works perfect. Thanks. As for the html, it was my mistake, since the second message had no html formatting. sorry. I'm going to update my new question with this improved version of the script.

Comment: @VíctorEnrich please accept the answer by clicking on the green tick